# Sort Pivot Table

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, pivot

I run into an issue where the Macro states:

> Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object defined error.

But I thought I did define it?  I have defined WS1 previously in this code and have no issues with that part. It is the last line of code in this section that has issues.

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
'Update Pivot Table
    Dim GroupPivot As PivotTable
    Set GroupPivot = WS1.PivotTables("GroupPivot")
    GroupPivot.PivotCache.Refresh

'Sort PivotTable
    WS1.PivotTables("GroupPivot").PivotFields("Sum of Discrepancy").AutoSort Order:=xlDescending, Type:=xlSortValues
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing (that isn't the problem) is that you defined GroupPivot on the third line, but on the last line you don't use it.
Second (which is the problem), you are not using the correct parameter names. The two required parameters for AutoSort are Order and Field.
The last line should look something like this:

```
GroupPivot.PivotFields("Sum of Discrepancy").AutoSort Order:=xlDescending, Field:="Discrepancy"
```

but the field name above might not be correct. It should match the SourceName of the pivot field